# Why does the atof() function not return 0 when I pass it a string with invalid characters after a number?

Tags: c, ansi-c, atof

I need to convert a string into a float. If the string is not a number I wish to return 0.

I have tried to test if the `atof()` function would work for this by using the following code:

```
printf("%f", atof("1a"));
```

From my understanding of atof, the value returned when atof cannot convert is 0, and yet this line prints `1.0`.

Why does this happen? By the documentation I understood that atof is meant to return 0 whenever the input is not a number.

Comment: you might be better off using: `strtod()`.  Do note that `atof()` actually returns a `double`, not a `float`.   Note: the function: `atof()` will see the `1` as a valid number and return the result of the conversion: 1.000000.  There is no reason for it to return 0.000000 as there is a valid number to convert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/). Emphasis mine

> The function first discards as many whitespace characters (as in
>   isspace) as necessary until the first non-whitespace character is
>   found. Then, starting from this character, **takes as many characters
>   as possible that are valid following a syntax resembling that of
>   floating point literals (see below), and interprets them as a
>   numerical value. The rest of the string after the last valid character
>   is ignored and has no effect on the behavior of this function.**

Answer (score 1):

I saw that you checked some documentation, but you must have missed the emphasized part - it's important to make sure you read documentation thoroughly: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/

> The function first discards as many whitespace characters (as in isspace) as necessary until the first non-whitespace character is found. Then, starting from this character, takes as many characters as possible that are valid following a syntax resembling that of floating point literals (see below), and interprets them as a numerical value. **The rest of the string after the last valid character is ignored and has no effect on the behavior of this function.**

Thus, the function is behaving exactly as it should - the `a` character in `"1a"` is being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

> yet this line prints 1.0.

```
printf("%f", atof("1a"));
```

worked because `atof` could parse atleast one number ie `1` in this case.

But:

```
char a[]="a1";
printf("%f\n",atof(a));
```

should have given you a return value of 0.0 as you expected.